# How can I reset the program if the user inputs something not acceptable?

Tags: javascript

I'm making a ping pong game where I ask for user input on their paddles. I have the screen and one paddle showing up and some user input for how they want to customize their paddle. But after asking for input, how can I rerun the program when the user inputs something not acceptable?

This is my code so far:

```html
 

<html>
<canvas id="gameArea" width="1000" height="800"></canvas>

<script>
let canvas;
let canvasContext;
let ballX = 0;
let padH = prompt("how long would you like your paddle? 70 to 110 are good values");
let padL = prompt("how wide would you like your paddle 2? 1 to 15 are good values");
let padColor = prompt("What color paddle do you want?");
const colors = ["white","red","blue","green","purple","aqua","brown","cyan","yellow"]

handleInput(padColor,padL,padH)

window.onload = function() {
  canvas = document.getElementById('gameArea');
  canvasContext = canvas.getContext('2d');

  setInterval(gameRender,10);
}

function handleInput(padColor,padL,padH) {
  if (colors.indexOf(padColor) !== -1) {
    return;
  } else {
    alert("that color is not supported")
  }
  if (70 < padH < 110) {
    alert("please enter an acceptable value")
  } else {
    return;
  }
  if (1 < padL < 15) {
    alert("please enter an acceptable value")
  } else {
    return;
  }
}

function gameRender() {
  ballX = ballX + 20;
  canvasContext.fillStyle = 'black';
  canvasContext.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
  canvasContext.fillStyle = padColor;
  canvasContext.fillRect(10,(canvas.height-padH)/2,padL,padH);
  canvasContext.fillStyle = 'white'
  canvasContext.fillRect(ballX,100,10,10)
}

gameRender()
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Example: https://javascript.info/task/repeat-until-correct

Answer (score 2):

You can have a function `promptPaddle()` or something similar, which you can call again:

```js
function promptPaddle() {
    let padH = prompt("how long would you like your paddle? 70 to 110 are good values");
    let padL = prompt("how wide would you like your paddle 2? 1 to 15 are good values");
    let padColor = prompt("What color paddle do you want?");
    handleInput(padColor, padL, padH)
}

const colors = ["white", "red", "blue", "green", "purple", "aqua", "brown", "cyan", "yellow"]

function handleInput(padColor, padL, padH) {
    if (colors.indexOf(padColor) === -1) {
        alert("that color is not supported");
        return promptPaddle();
    }
    if (70 < padH || padH < 110) {
        alert("please enter an acceptable value");
        return promptPaddle();
    }
    if (1 < padL || padL < 15) {
        alert("please enter an acceptable value");
        return promptPaddle();
    }
    // Got proper input, do whatever now
}

// Need to call it once to start the process
promptPaddle();
```

I should mention that it might be better to do this "loop validation" for each prompt separately. Right now, you can enter a wrong `padH` but otherwise a correct `padL` and `padColor`, but only after you've entered all 3 values will it go "actually your first value was already wrong, now re-enter all 3 again".

Comment: thanks so much for the reponse didnt really expect any. Im new to programming so thanks alot

Comment: im sorry i still dont understand

Comment: Your question was decently written and showed some effort, so unless it's a very complex question that's hard to answer, you'll usually get a quick response. And lots of people here like people that try to learn

Comment: @ZayanHasan Basically, your program will go `Ask question > check input > handle input`. If `check input` sees the input is wrong, you'd go back to `Ask question`. That's what my code does: `promptPadde()` asks the questions, `handleInput()` checks the inputs, and if there's a mistake, it returns to `promptPaddle()`. Otherwise it'll continue doing whatever `handleInput()` is supposed to do (which I marked with a simple comment)

Comment: lol thanks, but when i run this program it says uncaught error in line 18: colors not defined btw its the line right after function handle input

Comment: Ah, I just noticed I moved that `const colors` into the wrong place. My code was more of an overview of "you can do more or less this", not a perfect piece of code you could just copy-paste. I'll change it anyway

Comment: oh i see so where can i see it updating

Comment: Yay it works but even when i enter an acceptable value for the paddle it stills says to enter a acceptable one

Comment: should i add like an else statement that just continues the program if the input is acceptable, and if so, how?

Comment: @ZayanHasan I basically copied your comparison and just noticed you're using `70 < padH < 110`. I should've caught that, but that's not proper JavaScript, Well, _it is_, but it's checking `(70 < padH) < 110`, e.g. `someBoolean < 110`. You probably meant to use `(70 < padH) || (padH < 110)` instead

Comment: im stuck in a loop and cant go to the website screen, its just asking me to reenter a better input

Comment: Pressing F5 (or worst case, ctrl+W to close the tab) should get you out of the loop and allow you to reopen the site after fixing the code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235071/discussion-between-kelvin-schoofs-and-zayan-hasan).

Comment: ok i made the change in the inequality comparison.

Comment: i quit i cant do it